# How to change font size of title in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

this is the code ,this will show the default size, i want to change the font size of the title becoz this title is too big n not showing the whole only "Cook Great Indian..." is showing...pl let me help out

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.title = @"Cook Great Indian Recipes";
}
```

Comment: From xib's attribute inspector, you can achieve it eaisly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not change the font of `title`. Instead create a `UILabel` with your own customization and assign it as *navigationItem's* `titleView`.

```
UILabel *titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.frame = CGRectMake(...
label.font = [UIFont ...
// And the other things
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLbl;
[titleLbl release];
```

Answer (score 12):

Try setting custom label for title label:

```
    self.title = @"Cook Great Indian Recipes";
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [self.title sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0]].width, 44);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
    label.text = self.title;
    [label release];
```